# MS Access: Group and Count Total of Specific Value

Tags: ms-access

I have a table called submissions with over 20,000 records in Microsoft Access, which looks like this

```
Sub no  Support/oppose
1111    Support
1111    Support
1111    Oppose in part
1121    Oppose
1121    Oppose
1122    Support
1122    Support in part
```

I would like to produce a query which presents the data in this format.

```
Sub no  Support Support in part Oppose  Oppose in part
1111    2   0   0   1
1121    0   0   2   0
1122    1   1   0   0
```

I've tried other queries on this site, which solve similar problems but nothing that produces the result im after.

It's basically a grouping of sub no, counting the number of Support, Support in part, Oppose, Oppose in part which is contained in one column in the submission table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at crosstabs?

Comment: I hadn't till now. Thanks so much, have just set it up. Does exactly what I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A crosstab query should suit : http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-HA010229577.aspx